# Approximation result of a multivariate optimization problem using two different approaches

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have an optimization problem of the form

$$
\text{minimize }_{\mathbf{U,P,Q}} \quad||\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{PQ}||^2 + ||\mathbf{Y-UP'}||^2 + ||\mathbf{U}||^2
$$

I can solve this using Alternating minimization (AM) i.e. in each iteration solve for one variable keeping the others constant and in subsequent iteration use the most recent value of the variable. 
Another approach could be, I can first solve for

$$
\text{minimize }_{\mathbf{P,Q}} \quad||\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{PQ}||^2 
$$
using AM and then get values for $\mathbf{P,Q}$ and use the obtained value of $\mathbf{P}$ to solve

$$
\text{minimize }_{\mathbf{U}} \quad ||\mathbf{Y-UP'}||^2 + ||\mathbf{U}||^2
$$

exactly.

Is there any study on the quality of the two approaches ?  What can we say about the approximation error in both cases ?  Any pointers please ?

Comment: So I presume that $\bf P'$ is $\bf P$ transposed or some such thing? 

Could be good to write such things down in the question for clarity.

Comment: Yes, it is transpose only.

Comment: It is a very interesting problem, but I don't have any good references. Only a few of my own experiments which are rather rough and un-validated, so far.

Comment: @mathreadler, any pointers, just to get started, will be helpful to me.  I am trying to understand which gives better approximation i.e. lower error, even an intuition will be fine.